# Google Apps API Impersonation - HTTPS/REST

Tags: api, rest, google-apps, impersonation, gdata

This will seem like an already answered question, but I promise it is not...at least not "answered".

Working with Google Apps for Business. Have a specific need to write an https/REST client - not using JAVA/PYTHON or compiled code such as .NET. Going through the Google Data API documentation was straightforward until I tried to query information for any user other than the admin. All needed scopes have been authorized at the domain level (Manage API access...etc). Each time I try to query the data for another user, I get the message that you can't access data for another user. **I know this sounds familiar...but please read on.** There are specific constructs for creating the CLAIM Set in JAVA, Python, and .NET to allow impersonation. However, there does not appear to be a corresponding one for straight HTTPS/REST calls.

I've tried working with both "sub" and "prn" when creating the CLAIM set. I've tried various combinations of the admin user and the user to be impersonated w/o success. I'm fairly certain at this point that there is a missing construct to be used in the creation of the CLAIM set for a straight HTTPS/REST call.

It is the FLUX Capacitor that I seek.

In JAVA, it appears to be: **setServiceAccountUser**. Other Google examples use similar constructs but there appears to be nothing documented [that works] for HTTPS/REST calls. This is odd as it appears that every other GData function would/will work to administratively access user data.

Has anyone successfully accessed non-admin (google apps for business) user data using just https/rest calls --not using the libraries for the specific languages? There are several hundred users for which the internal app must provide services. The authorize per user route isn't a go...which is why we chose the delegated access at the domain level.

Any help would be greatly appreciated....even if it is confirmation that what we are seeking is not possible.

TIA...

Answer (score 1):

So it turned out that I had the FLUX Capacitor. I just didn't realize it because I was simply trying to do to much in my scripts at once. The **SUB** value in the JSON_Request was the right thing to do. PRN is deprecated and anything else is simply ignored. One of the factors preventing my impersonation with this approach was the combination of scopes I was attempting and quasi succeeding to authorize. Through the research and countless hours in Google's Playground I realized that my resulting TOKEN didn't look like the others. The Sesame Street song... "One of These Things is not like the others..." came to mind. Accordingly, after reducing the scope (for the respective Google API Service) down to the minimum and removing any HTTP header value not specifically required; I was able to get the script properly act on behalf of our users.

The token I was receiving looked more like a REFRESH TOKEN than an initial token response. It wasn't worth the time to determine what exact privs. were enabled by that token but based on the fairly consistent behavior I plan to script logic into the solution to detect when a "useless" token response has been received.

Those of you who now how to code in JAVA, .Net, Ruby, Python...etc. may wonder why I didn't take those routes. One of the requirements for the solution was that it be as lite as possible and correspondingly as few dependencies as possible. While more cumbersome, this approach employed REST calls in its most raw form with the only dependency being the certificate file and the respective host machine's computational ability (uh and its ability to keep time).

Ultimately it was a "Minimum Viable Product" (The LEAN Startup by Eric Ries) ...now to time to make it pretty :-)